# code for fetch text box value button click using react js

Tags: reactjs

If I have a two Text Box and one submit Button, By clicking on the submit button I need to get and display the two text box values in the same page without getting page refreshing like posting comment in Facebook.  For this I need to use reactjs. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? i recomend you find some examples and if you have any issue ask a more concrete question.

Comment: Have you not seen the react tutorial?  http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: http://blog.iansinnott.com/managing-state-and-controlled-form-fields-with-react/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. Just make a sample page for fetching data from textboxes. There is also other ways in React Js for this but i found this way.

**HTML File:**

```
<div id="TestButton"></div>
```

**JSX file:**

```
  /** @jsx React.DOM */

var TestText = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {author: '', text: '',
           Values : ''
           };
  },
  handleAuthorChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({author: e.target.value});
  },
  handleTextChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var author = this.state.author.trim();
    var text = this.state.text.trim();
    if (text != "" || author!="") {
      var vals= "";
      this.setState({vals:"FirstName:"+author+","+"Say LastName:"+text })
      return vals;
    }
    // TODO: send request to the server
    this.setState({author:'' , text:'' });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Your name"
          value={this.state.author}
          onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Say something..."
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange={this.handleTextChange}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      <br/>
      <span>{this.state.vals}</span>
      </form>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<TestText/>, document.getElementById('TestButton'));
```

[DemoCodePen](http://codepen.io/har_kaur17/pen/gPqOzY)